# Carrierwave direct upload to s3 with sidekiq failing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave, sidekiq

Following the Ryan Bates tutorial on direct uploading to S3 using CarrierWave and background jobs with Sidekiq.

I am seeing the following error in the background worker from the sidekiq log.

```
    2012-11-10T14:33:56Z 44401 TID-owd2xrzdg WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Article::ImageWorker", "args"=>[44, "uploads/d8850e90-0d6d-0130-fecf-3c0754129341/mkv5E.jpg"], "jid"=>"8add5079541725ad30550f9c", "error_message"=>"Validation failed: Image could not download file", "error_class"=>"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid", "failed_at"=>"2012-11-10T14:29:15Z", "retry_count"=>4, "retried_at"=>2012-11-10 14:33:56 UTC}
    2012-11-10T14:33:56Z 44401 TID-owd2xrzdg WARN: Validation failed: Image could not download file
    2012-11-10T14:33:56Z 44401 TID-owd2xrzdg WARN: /Users/kgoddard/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
```

Here is my Uploader

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include CarrierWave direct uploader to background upload task.
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Set the mimetype of the upload incase it is incorrect.
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  process :resize_to_limit => [640, 640]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [160, 120]
  end

end
```

The Article Model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :orientation, :shoot_id, :image
  belongs_to :shoot
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  after_save :enqueue_image

  def image_name
    File.basename(image.path || image.filename) if image
  end

  def enqueue_image
    ImageWorker.perform_async(id, key) if key.present?
  end

  class ImageWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform(id, key)
        article = Article.find(id)
        article.key = key
        article.remote_image_url = article.image.direct_fog_url(:with_path => true)
        article.save!
        article.update_column(:image_processed, true)
    end

  end

end
```

CarrierWave config

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],       # required
    :region                 => 'eu-east-1'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]                       # required
end
```

Shoot controller show action that is responsible for rendering the upload form

```
  # GET /shoots/1
  # GET /shoots/1.json
  def show
    # TODO: is this the best way to prevent users from accessing not owned resources.
    @shoot = Shoot.find(params[:id])
    @uploader = Article.new.image
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_admin_article_url    
    if @shoot
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
      end
    else
      redirect_to shoots_path, alert: 'No shoot found with id: #{params[:id]}'
    end
  end
```

Form for show action uploader

```
<div class="hero-unit">
  <h2><%= @shoot.name %></h2>
  <p><%= @shoot.overview %></p>
  <p>This shoot was taken on <%= @shoot.shoot_date %></p>
  <%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "article[image]" %></p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Add Media", :class => "btn btn-primary" %></p>
  <% end %>
</div><!-- /hero-unit -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my bucket name was invalid... Make sure that your bucket name only includes letters, numbers and dashes.

Comment: Also, you don't need to say storage :fog -- CarrierWave Direct does that by default.